# Querying TypeORM Inherited Entities: Specific Fields Undefined

Tags: typeorm

I have 3 entity classes:

```js
import {Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, TableInheritance} from "typeorm"
import {ChatMessage} from "./ChatMessage.js"

@Entity({schema: "chat"})
@TableInheritance({ column: { name: "type", type: "varchar" } })
export abstract class Chat {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string

  @Column()
  type: string

  @Column({ type: "timestamptz", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  createdAt: Date

  @Column({ type: "timestamptz", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  modifiedAt: Date

  @OneToMany(() => ChatMessage, (chatMessage) => chatMessage.chat)
  chatMessages: Array<ChatMessage>
}
```

```js
import {Entity, ManyToOne, Relation} from "typeorm"
import {Chat} from "./Chat.js"
import {Profile} from "../app/Profile.js"

@Entity({schema: "chat"})
export class PrivateChat extends Chat {
  @ManyToOne(() => Profile, { nullable: false })
  member1: Relation<Profile>

  @ManyToOne(() => Profile, { nullable: false })
  member2: Relation<Profile>
}
```

```js
import {Column, Entity, OneToMany} from "typeorm"
import {Chat} from "./Chat.js"
import {GroupChatMember} from "./GroupChatMember.js"

@Entity({schema: "chat"})
export class GroupChat extends Chat {
  @Column({type: "varchar", length: 32})
  name: string

  @Column({type: "varchar", length: 255})
  image: string

  @OneToMany(() => GroupChatMember, (chatMember) => chatMember.chat)
  chatMembers: Array<GroupChatMember>
}
```

This results in 3 database tables, where `chat` contains the common fields and `private_chat` and `group_chat` contain the common and additional the specific fields.
Now I can query all chats:

```js
await AppDataSource.getRepository(Chat).createQueryBuilder().getMany()
```

Then I get a result like this:

```
[
  PrivateChat {
    id: 'be73a90c-79c9-4f6f-98fd-b1cde765c1e6',
    type: 'PrivateChat',
    createdAt: 2023-12-11T16:31:39.093Z,
    modifiedAt: 2023-12-11T16:31:39.093Z,
    chatMessages: undefined,
    member1: undefined,
    member2: undefined
  },
  GroupChat {
    id: '0283cef2-0411-4d32-80b9-e446fab3c017',
    type: 'GroupChat',
    createdAt: 2023-12-11T16:31:39.093Z,
    modifiedAt: 2023-12-11T16:31:39.093Z,
    chatMessages: undefined,
    name: undefined,
    image: undefined,
    chatMembers: undefined
  }
]
```

As you can see the specific fields are undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use single table inheritance now because I feel that TypeORM doesn't support another suitable solution. I think it's not entirely clean because of nullable fields which are not really nullable. It would be better to join the tables with the concrete data. But it seems that this isn't supported by TypeORM.

Changes in code are:

```js
@Entity({schema: "chat"})
@TableInheritance({ column: { name: "type", type: "varchar" } })
export abstract class Chat {
    ...
}
```

```js
@ChildEntity()
export class PrivateChat extends Chat {
    ...
}
```

```js
@ChildEntity()
export class GroupChat extends Chat {
    ...
}
```

Now it's one table and querying is easy.